# Data retrieval with AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to call to mysql server to retrieve a couple products and convert them to tables, but it doesn't seem to be working at all.

I'm just learning server side so any explanation would be awesome, thanks guys!

list.php:

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:localhost:8888;dbname=searchable-db', 'pim-admin', 'admin');
$select = 'SELECT *';
$from = ' FROM `products`';
$where = ' WHERE TRUE';
$sql = $select . $from . $where;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute*();
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PD0::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
echo($json);
?>
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>AJAX Filtering</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css">
    </head>


    <body>
        <h1>Product Database</h1>
        <div id="products"></div>

        <table id="pieces">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th>Material</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Style</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            </tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            function updateProducts(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "list.php",
                    dataTyoe : 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(records){
                      $('#products').text(JSON.stringify(records, null, 4));
                    }
                });
            }

            updateProducts();

            function makeTable(data){
                var tbl_body = "";
                $.each(data, function() {
                var tbl_row = "";
                $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
                })
                tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>"; 
                })
                 return tbl_body;
            }

            $('#pieces tbody').html(makeTable(records));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

@SmileOff, this is what I have now in place, no errors and still can't call my data in :/

```
<script>
    function updateProducts(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "includes/list.php",
                    success: function(records){
                        console.log($.parseJSON(records));
                    } 
                });

    updateProducts();

            function makeTable(data){
                var tbl_body = "";
                $.each(data, function() {
                var tbl_row = "";
                $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
                })
                tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>"; 
                })
                 return tbl_body;
            }

            $('#pieces tbody').html(makeTable('records'));
        </script>
```

=================
@SmileOff

JS

```
function updateProducts(){
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/list.php",
                success: function(){
                    console.log($.parseJSON(records));
                }
            });
        }

            updateProducts();

                function makeTable(data){
                    var tbl_body = "";
                    $.each(data, function() {
                    var tbl_row = "";
                    $.each(this, function(k, v) {
                    tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
                    })
                    tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>"; 
                    })
                 return tbl_body;
                }
            $('#pieces tbody').html(makeTable('records'));
```

List.php

```
<?php
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:8888;dbname=searchable-db', 'pim-admin', 'admin'); 
  $select = 'SELECT *'; 
  $from = ' FROM products'; 
  $where = ' WHERE TRUE'; 
  $sql = $select . $from . $where; 
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();
  $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json=json_encode($results);
  echo($json);
?>
```

Comment: `->execute*()`? `PD0::FETCH`? You've got a bunch of outright syntax errors in your code. Plus, your `hello word` echo is just introducing syntax errors into the JSON code your code would be otherwise generating, if it wasn't for all the OTHER syntax errors.

Comment: Is your MySQL database actually running on port 8888?  I only ask because that's non-standard.

Comment: to access my database, I use localhost:8888, so I believe that is the correct link.

Comment: @user3307806: Where are you accessing your database from?  You're not entering `localhost:8888` into your web browser are you?

Comment: I've fixed my issue, but to enter my db, I use localhost:8888/whatever-file.  Mine was an SQL error, when ever I write a table in the phpadmin, it never seems to work, I always have to write it from command line. it's a very odd issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change this:
dataTyoe : 'json' - there is no dataTyoe, only dataType
cache: false - this is default, you dont need to set this again

```
$(function(){


         function updateProducts(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "testData.php",
                success: function(records){
                    console.log($.parseJSON(records));
                    makeTable($.parseJSON(records));

                }
            });
        }

        updateProducts();
        function makeTable(data){
            console.log(data);
            //update your html or something else
        }

    });
```

In your php file write down this, just for test

```
<?php


    echo json_encode(array(
        array(
            "id" => 2,
            "title" => "MVC architecture in JS",
            "price" => 89.00,
            "cover" => "mvc.jpg"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 3,
            "title" => "JavaScript - Good Parts",
            "price" => 99.99,
            "cover" => "good-parts.jpg"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 4,
            "title" => "JavaScript Design Patterns",
            "price" => 149.50,
            "cover" => "patterns.jpg"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 5,
            "title" => "3D World with Three.js",
            "price" => 299.00,
            "cover" => "three.jpg"
        )
    ));



   ?>
```

Comment: @ the poster, has your problem been cleared or do you still need further assistance

Comment: I am still unable to get mine to display properly.

Comment: remove dataType at all and try it again

Comment: For the $.post am I replacing my "$.ajax"? also, "data which will be send to server or null" Am I changing this? I am trying to retrieve data, not send it?

Comment: i'm understood that, so left null, yes $.post just a shorthand method of $.ajax - its the same things

Comment: I am now getting a server error, so i'm assuming the path to either my script, or local host is wrong..
POST http://localhost:8888/mysql-pim/includes/list.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: you should call this function makeTable(data) in success function, because this function executes before, async tech)) did you try with my php example, mb you have some errors in PHP file

Comment: Nothing is echoing so I'm assuming something tis broken in mine.

Comment: function updateProducts(){ - you do not close bracket of this function

Comment: 100% working example, i cant check your database, coz i dont have it

Comment: Mine still is not working, but I have resolved it as being a Database error, since you helped me come to the conclusion, I'm gonna mark it as answered. Thanks for all your help! I really appreciate it!